# How can I add a directory to my PATH?

Tags: paths, environment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add a directory to my path?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path)

I created a `.bash_aliases` file with the following contents:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/opt/bin
```

So it adds `/home/myuser/opt/bin` to `$PATH`.
I made this because I don't have root access to this machine.

When I run apps interactively through the shell command line, they can understand my custom PATH with no problems. But, if I open a app outside the shell command line, for example, choosing from the unity dash, the same apps can't see my custom PATH.

I tried putting `shopt -s expand_aliases` in my `.bash_aliases`, but without success.

How can I set a PATH for environments other than BASH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running apps outside the shell command line that *will always* run with your UID, you can create *session*-wide environment variables by adding them to `~/.pam_environment`, rather than `.bash_aliases`.

If you're running apps outside the shell command line that *will not always* run with your UID, *system*-wide environment variables by adding them to `/etc/environment`, rather than `.bash_aliases`.

**However**: Creating ***system***-wide environment variables will affect ***ALL*** users, including root. If the variable you set overwrites another, ***bad*** things will happen. Adding something onto the end of `PATH` doesn't *seem* like it will cause any havoc, but seeing as you don't have root, you would need your sysadmin to do it for you, and s/he can probably advise you as to whether it is safe to add it. Whether s/he actually allows you to do this is something else entirely; anything user-related is best kept within the config files within their home folder, and it is not normally 'done' to have a users configuration affecting the whole system!

Comment: Thank you for the Answer. 
I add the following to my ~/.pam_environment:
"PATH DEFAULT=${PATH}:~/opt/bin"
And I change the line 50 in /etc/pam.d/login for avoid duplicate my env like this:
"session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0"

Answer (score 1):

The PATH environment variable does not belong in ~/.bash_aliases; a better place is  ~/.profile or ~/.pam_environment recently. If you put your path in ~/.profile, it will be available to X and the window managers that use X. Edit ~/.profile. Add to the end of that file:

`PATH="$PATH:$HOME/opt/bin"`

Maybe you are using Xubuntu? You may need to use ~/.bashrc instead. And ~/.pam_environment:

`PATH DEFAULT=${PATH}:~/opt/bin`

See [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Session-wide_environment_variables) on Environment variables.

What does belong in ~/.bash_aliases are command aliases, like this:

```
alias l=ls
alias ll=ls -l
alias la=la -la
alias x=exit
alias b=my-insanely-long-command-i-never-want-to-type-again
```